# Replace a blown breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

Hey :) I have a blown breaker. I live in a townhouse and there is no main shut off in my place. I took the cover off the panel, shut off that breaker, did a voltage test on the wires and no alarm so I removed the wires. I tried wiggling the breaker but it wouldn’t come out then realize it’s a bolt in breaker. Used my voltage tester at that acre holding it on and alarm is going off, now I’m afraid to touch that screw to get it out. It’s for our baseboard heater and northern Canadian winter, need heat ASAP. Do I need an electrician or is that bolt safe to remove then I just put a new breaker in?

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel? Also, have you tried looking for your main shutoff by the electric meters for the building?

Answer (score 4):

If I am reading this question right, you couldn't find the main for your panel, so you decided to try to replace the breaker for a dead heating circuit in the live panel.  Lee Ho Fook.  That could have gotten ugly.

No offense intended and I may be reading the question wrong, but do you realize breakers are not one-time protection devices like fuses?  You can reset a breaker by turning it off then back on if it trips.  **You should do this just once and if it trips again, leave it off until the fault that's tripping it is diagnosed and rectified.**  Don't reset it over and over hoping it will hold.

If that doesn't work for you, call in an electrician.

Replacing a breaker in a live panel is never ideal, a safety conscious electrician will avoid it if at all possible, it might be unavoidable in a some critical facilities, never really ought to happen in residential.  For DIY, just don't do it.

I reiterate, if you can't figure out how to de-energize something to work on it, DON'T WORK ON IT HOT, call in reinforcements.

Comment: Le Ho Fook or Ho Lee Fook? Either way, a voltage tester light vs a meter are two totally different tools and for anyone that reads this, the voltage tester light is just a quick sanity check tool. Never rely on one of these like a bible. its a blessing Melonie had the presnce of mind to proceed with caution, but disturbing that they proceeded nonetheless. If you have the breaker, you should already know how it goes in. Breakers rarely fail, if it failed, it got wet/corroded, or worse... Call an electrician. They are probably running portable heaters on 15A circuits... more is likely wrong

Comment: Lee Ho Fook, gonna get a big dish of beef chow mein. Warren Zevon... nice

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it sounds like you have bolt-down breakers such as Pushmatic or some Siemens.  The latter are still popular in industry, this is to keep non-qualified workers/managers from tampering with the panel.

It also sounds like you did exactly the right thing, checked for voltage on the bolt-down and backed away from the job when you realized it was "hot".  That is correct; the bolt-down is meant to be "hot" unless it is merely a tie-down for a backfeed breaker.

I presume, from this level of skill, that you know breakers can be reset.  Usually you throw the switch. Though in Pushmatic, well, obviously you push those, but if I recall sometimes you push them twice - once from "tripped to off" then once from "off to on".  You can feel the difference because "off to on" is an impressive amount of force.  If you're giving that a sensible amount of force, try somewhat more :)

I violently disrecommend trying to swap one with the power on.

If your main breaker is not readily obvious, there are several possibilities.

- This is a subpanel, and its main breaker is in the main panel.  Find it, turn it off.
- The main breaker is somewhere else, presumably out at the meter.  Find it, turn it off.
- This is a "Rule of Six" panel.  Follow the main conductors in, and see where they land on some large lugs.  Near those lugs will be 4-6 double spaces (8-12 normal breaker spaces) marked "Main Disconnects" on the panel cover.  Those "six" together are your main breaker.  (This was done because at one time, breakers over 60A were prohibitively expensive).  These are hot all the time.  You cannot de-energize the bus in this "Rule of Six" area except by pulling the meter or having the power company signal their smart meter to disconnect.  *The rest of the panel has a separate bus.  It is fed by one of the "Six" breakers.  That bus can be de-energized by turning off that breaker*.

If you are simply unable to de-energize the panel, as a temporary workaround you can feed the electric heat from any two already-installed breakers, provided they are smaller or equal to the heater breaker's amp rating (to protect the wires)  and they are on opposite poles (otherwise it won't work).  On Pushmatics, the left and right rails are opposite poles in the same column of breakers.  Some Pushmatics have 2 columns.  Not sure on Siemens.  Disconnect the load wire that is already on the breaker, or you can keep it if the breaker is listed for 2 wires.  (Pushmatics are). Be careful not to trip those breakers!